# How to distribute strings in Emacs or Vim

Tags: vim, emacs

In Emacs or Vim, what's a smooth way to join strings as in this example:

```
Transform from:
    (alpha, beta, gamma) blah (123, 456, 789)
To:
    (alpha=123, beta=456, gamma=789)
```

It would need to scale to:

- many lines of these
- many elements in the parentheses

I have recently found myself needing this kind of transformation often.

I use Evil in Emacs which is why a Vim answer would likely also help.

UPDATE:

The solutions were not as general as I had hoped.  For example, I'd like the solution to also work when I have a list of strings and wish to distribute them into a large XML document.  eg:

```
<item foo="" bar="barval1"/>
<item foo="" bar="barval2"/>
<item foo="" bar="barval3"/>
<item foo="" bar="barval4"/>

fooval1
fooval2
fooval3
fooval4
```

I formulated a solution and have added it as an answer.

Comment: is "blah" fixed or random text too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach is to create one command to set a match-list, then use replace-regexp as the second command to distribute match-list, leveraging replace-regexp's existing \, facility.

Evaluate Elisp, such as in the .emacs file:

```
(defvar match-list nil
  "A list of matches, as set through the set-match-list and consumed by the cycle-match-list function. ")
(defvar match-list-iter nil
  "Iterator through the global match-list variable. ")
(defun reset-match-list-iter ()
  "Set match-list-iter to the beginning of match-list and return it. "
  (interactive)
  (setq match-list-iter match-list))
(defun make-match-list (match-regexp use-regexp beg end)
  "Set the match-list variable as described in the documentation for set-match-list. "
  ;; Starts at the beginning of region, searches forward and builds match-list.
  ;; For efficiency, matches are appended to the front of match-list and then reversed
  ;; at the end.
  ;;
  ;; Note that the behavior of re-search-backward is such that the same match-list
  ;; is not created by starting at the end of the region and searching backward.
  (let ((match-list nil))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char beg)
      (while
          (let ((old-pos (point)) (new-pos (re-search-forward match-regexp end t)))
            (when (equal old-pos new-pos)
              (error "re-search-forward makes no progress.  old-pos=%s new-pos=%s end=%s match-regexp=%s"
                     old-pos new-pos end match-regexp))
            new-pos)
        (setq match-list
              (cons (replace-regexp-in-string match-regexp
                                              use-regexp
                                              (match-string 0)
                                              t)
                    match-list)))
      (setq match-list (nreverse match-list)))))
(defun set-match-list (match-regexp use-regexp beg end)
  "Set the match-list global variable to a list of regexp matches.  MATCH-REGEXP
is used to find matches in the region from BEG to END, and USE-REGEXP is the
regexp to place in the match-list variable.

For example, if the region contains the text: {alpha,beta,gamma}
and MATCH-REGEXP is: \\([a-z]+\\),
and USE-REGEXP is: \\1
then match-list will become the list of strings: (\"alpha\" \"beta\")"
  (interactive "sMatch regexp: \nsPlace in match-list: \nr")
  (setq match-list (make-match-list match-regexp use-regexp beg end))
  (reset-match-list-iter))
(defun cycle-match-list (&optional after-end-string)
  "Return the next element of match-list.

If AFTER-END-STRING is nil, cycle back to the beginning of match-list.
Else return AFTER-END-STRING once the end of match-list is reached."
  (let ((ret-elm (car match-list-iter)))
    (unless ret-elm
      (if after-end-string
          (setq ret-elm after-end-string)
        (reset-match-list-iter)
        (setq ret-elm (car match-list-iter))))
    (setq match-list-iter (cdr match-list-iter))
    ret-elm))
(defadvice replace-regexp (before my-advice-replace-regexp activate)
  "Advise replace-regexp to support match-list functionality. "
  (reset-match-list-iter))
```

Then to solve the original problem:

```
M-x set-match-list
Match regexp: \([0-9]+\)[,)]
Place in match-list: \1

M-x replace-regexp
Replace regexp: \([a-z]+\)\([,)]\)
Replace regexp with: \1=\,(cycle-match-list)\2
```

And to solve the XML example:

```
[Select fooval strings.]
M-x set-match-list
Match regexp: .+
Place in match-list: \&

[Select XML tags.]
M-x replace-regexp
Replace regexp: foo=""
Replace regexp with: foo="\,(cycle-match-list)"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
%s/(\(\S\{-}\), \(\S\{-}\), \(\S\{-}\)).\{-}(\(\S\{-}\), \(\S\{-}\), \(\S\{-}\))/(\1=\4, \2=\5, \3=\6)
```

`%s`: global search and replace

`\(\S{-}\),`: non greedy search for non-whitespace characters up to the next comma, enclosed by "(" for backreferencing

`\1=\4` : prints out the first match, an "=" sign, then the fourth match

Comment: Wow, that's very nice! But does it work with lists of more than three elements?

Comment: as is, no, but it could be extended to do so. im not sure if there is a way to write a dynamic regex that could handle variables and whatnot... i guess thats where sed and awk come in.

Answer (score 2):

for such text transformation, I would go with awk:

this one-liner may help:

```
awk -F'\\(|\\)' '{split($2,t,",");split($4,v,",");printf "( "; for(x in t)s=s""sprintf("%s=%s, ", t[x],v[x]);sub(", $","",s);printf s")\n";s=""}' file
```

little test:

```
kent$  cat test
(alpha, beta, gamma) blah (123, 456, 789)
(a, b, c) foo (1, 2, 3)
(x, y, z, m, n) bar (100, 200, 300, 400, 500)

kent$  awk -F'\\(|\\)' '{split($2,t,",");split($4,v,",");printf "( "; for(x in t)s=s""sprintf("%s=%s, ", t[x],v[x]);sub(", $","",s);printf s")\n";s=""}' test

( alpha=123,  beta= 456,  gamma= 789)
( a=1,  b= 2,  c= 3)
(  m= 400,  n= 500, x=100,  y= 200,  z= 300)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Vimscript solution. It is nowhere near as elegant as ash's answer, but it works with lists of any length.

```
function! ListMerge()
    " Get line, remove text between lists, split lists at parentheses:
    let curline = getline('.')
    let curline = substitute(curline,')\zs.*\ze(','','g')
    let curline = substitute(curline,'(','','g')
    let lists = map(split(curline,')'),'split(v:val,",")')
    " Return if we don't have two lists of equal length:
    if len(lists) != 2 || len(lists[0]) != len(lists[1])
        return
    endif
    " Loop over the lists, remove whitespace, build the replacement string:
    let i=0
    let string = '('
    while i<len(lists[0])
        let string .= substitute(lists[0][i],'^ *','','')
        let string .= '='
        let string .= substitute(lists[1][i],'^ *','','')
        let string .= ', '
        let i+=1
    endwhile
    " Add the concluding bracket:
    let string = substitute(string,', $',')','')
    " Replace the current line with the string:
    execute "normal! S" . string
endfunction
```

You can then call this function on all lines like this:

```
:%call ListMerge()
```

Answer (score 1):

Emacs Lisp version of Prince Goulash answer

```
(require 'cl)

(defun split-and-trim (str separator)
  (let ((strs (split-string str separator)))
    (mapcar (lambda (s)
              (replace-regexp-in-string "^\\s-+" "" s))
            (mapcar (lambda (s)
                      (replace-regexp-in-string "\\s-$" "" s)) strs))))

(defun my/merge-list (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (goto-char beg)
  (let ((endmark (set-mark end))
        (regexp "(\\([^)]+\\))[^(]+(\\([^)]+\\))"))
    (while (re-search-forward regexp end t)
      (let ((replace-start (match-beginning 0))
            (replace-end   (match-end 0))
            (keys-str (match-string-no-properties 1))
            (values-str (match-string-no-properties 2)))
        (let* ((keys (split-and-trim keys-str ","))
               (values (split-and-trim values-str ",")))
          (while (> (length keys) (length values))
            (setq values (append values '(""))))
          (let* ((pairs (mapcar* (lambda (k v)
                                   (format "%s=%s" k v)) keys values))
                 (transformed (format "(%s)" (mapconcat #'identity pairs ", "))))
            (goto-char replace-start)
            (delete-region replace-start replace-end)
            (insert transformed)))))
    (goto-char (marker-position endmark))))
```

For example, you select region as following

```
(alpha, beta, gamma)  blah (123, 456, 789)
(alpha, beta, gamma, delta)  blah (123, 456, 789, aaa)
```

After M-x my/merge-list

```
(alpha=123, beta=456, gamma=789)
(alpha=123, beta=456, gamma=789, delta=aaa)
```

Answer (score 1):

This method I'm going to describe is a bit wacky, but it involves the minimum amount of Elisp code I could manage.  It's only applicable if the lists to be joined can be interpreted as Lisp lists once the commas in them are removed.  Numbers and sequences of alphabetic characters, as in your example, would be fine.

First, make sure that the Common Lisp library is loaded:  <kbd>M-:</kbd>`(require 'cl)`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Now, starting with the cursor at the start of the first list:

<kbd>M-C-k</kbd>  ; kill-forward-sexp

<kbd>C-e</kbd>  ; move-end-of-line

<kbd>M-C-b</kbd>  ; backward-sexp

<kbd>M-C-k</kbd>  ; kill-forward-sexp

<kbd>C-a</kbd>  ; move-beginning-of-line

<kbd>C-k</kbd>  ; kill-line

Now `blah` (or whatever) is the first entry in the kill ring, the second list is the second entry, and the first list is the third entry.

Type `(`, then <kbd>M-:</kbd> (`eval-expression`), take a deep breath, and type this:

```
(loop with (a b) = (mapcar (lambda (x) (car (read-from-string (remove ?, x))))
                     (subseq kill-ring 1 3))
   for x in a for y in b do (insert (format "%s=%s, " y x)))
```

(I've broken it up for presentation purposes, but you can type it all on one line.)

Then finally <kbd>DEL</kbd><kbd>DEL</kbd>`)`, and you're done!  You could turn it into a macro, if you wanted.